# setting solver loop to change cell references, adjacent columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, solver

I'm trying to write a macro for quadratic optimisation. I have very limited VBA skills, but I manually used solver and recorded a macro, my code currently looks like this:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$179:$C$185", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$186", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$C$174", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$179:$C$185" _
    , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is make a solver loop so that the next time the C column in the cell references and target cell will change to D, everything else will stay the same. I want to do this for 20 adjacent columns, from C to V. any help will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @orkanoid , having a little bit of a hard time deciphering what you are trying to do- so when you say: "so that the next time the C column in the cell references and target cell will change to D, everything else will stay the same" are you saying you just need to extend the code which you have working above for column B to column V?

Comment: Hi @TheSilkCode , I want this to work for all columns between (and including) C and V. so the next step would be:

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$179:$D$185", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$186", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$174", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$179:$D$185" _
    , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

End Sub

and then for column E and so on. thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: I don't see what you just typed is different than your original code, but take a look at the sample code below and hopefully gets you close enough to the goalline you can push it across with few tweaks

Comment: I'll try your suggestion right now and see what happens, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumptions that I put in my comment above are correct, then the following code would do what you're looking for- however I couldn't test all of it because I don't have the code for the solver functions... see below:

```
Public Sub sampleCode()
Dim targetWS As Worksheet
Dim colCounter As Long
Dim colAddress As String
Dim colLetter As String

Set targetWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)   'Make sure to replace sheet(1) with sheet(<your sheet name>)
For colCounter = 3 To 22    'Loop through columns C through V
    'Get the column letter you want to run solver on
    colAddress = Replace(targetWS.Range("A1")(1, colCounter).address, "$", "")
    colLetter = Left(colAddress, InStr(1, colAddress, "1") - 1)
    SolverReset
    'Run solver but with the references being set by using colLetter
    SolverAdd CellRef:=colLetter & "179:" & colLetter & "185", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=colLetter & "186", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverOk SetCell:=colLetter & "174", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=colLetter & "179:" & colLetter & "185", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: I tried the code above and it said "Run-time error '9':Subscript out of range". Then I hit debug and the line that starts with "Set targetWS" was marked yellow.

Comment: Did you replace the `Sheets(1)` in `Set targetWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` with a reference to your sheet as I noted here: "'Make sure to replace sheet(1) with sheet(<your sheet name>)"

Comment: Oh yeah! This worked like a charm! Thanks a lot @TheSilkCode , when I put the sheet name between the brackets I ended up getting the "Run-time error '9':Subscript out of range". Then I tried it with "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)". I just had one sheet in the workbook anyway, and it worked great (after a few excel crashes). You really helped me big time, thanks again!

Comment: Yeah don't put the sheetname within the brackets, I just put them there to call your attention..

Comment: So the name of my sheet is Stil. how should the correct syntax be?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stil")`